# Get native element value in angular 10

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the native element value in Angular 10 but am getting an `undefined` instead

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[appOskInput]"
})
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

private onKey(key: string) {
  let element = this.el.nativeElement,
    console.log("element: "+ element.value);
}


<form-input
   appOskInput
   [data]="{
      formControlName: 'firstName',
      name: 'firstName'
   }">
</form-input>
```

Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like that:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[testDirective]' })

export class TestDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    let element = this.el.nativeElement;
    console.log(element);
  }

  @HostListener('keyup') KeyUp() {
    let element = this.el.nativeElement;

    console.log(element);
  }
}
```

You can try it out here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n4mq7a?file=src/app/directives/test.directive.ts

You need to open console in the right window (on the bottom is a "console" button)

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to bind the keyup or down event with your function.
Below code will help you.

```
  @HostListener('keyup')
    public onKey() {
        let element = this.el.nativeElement;
        console.log(element.value);
    }
```